# how to make a 2D Dyanmic array in function without using pointers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int addition(int sohaib[100][100], int waleed[100][100]) {
    int row, column;
    int sum[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = sohaib[i][j] + waleed[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            cout << sum[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int row, column;
    cout << "Enter the Rows and columns.   "; cin >> row >> column;
    int sohaib[100][100];
    int waleed[100][100];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            cin >> sohaib[i][j];
            cin >> waleed[i][j];
        }
    }
    addition(sohaib, waleed);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help with this code i finally managed to make it work but it doesnt display. And before this it was
int  addition(int sohaib[row][column], int waleed[row][column])
not working tho. Help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is your goal to have `addition` take different-sized arrays as arguments but no pointers? Guess you should take a look at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Kind of But not really Just want to Have dynamic arrays between Functions and also we havent studied vectors and pointers not allowed too.

Comment: ```int row, column;``` You never initialize ```row``` and ```column``` in ```addition```.

Comment: Why not use a `std::array<std::array<int, 100>, 100>` (if you know the dimensions at compile time) or `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` (if the dimensions are not known at compile time, say being based on user input)?   Both `std::array` and `std::vector` are part of the C++ standard library, and you don't need to use pointers to use them.  (They might be implemented using pointers behind the scenes, but that doesn't mean you need to use pointers to use them).

Comment: Variables row and column are not initialized. So there value is indeterminate. But you use it in the for loops as upper boundary. Therefore the beahviour is undefined. And you will not get any output. The compiler will warn you about that.

Comment: Row and column are not initialised in your function! And *if* you have fixed size arrays, you should replace those magic numbers (`100`) by a constant defined once at top of your file. Apart from, you don't need that `sum` array at all in your function, just replace the body of your first double for loop with `std::cout << sohaib[i][j] + waleed[i][j];` and drop the second loop entirely...

Comment: I would really like to help. But what do you mean with dynamic? Do you mean that the number of elements in the array will not be known before? And we need to create an array during run time? Can you please clarify? Because without pointers or some dynamic existing container like `std::vector` this will not be possible. Can you edit your question and paste the original assignment in it? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to return the `sum` array as dynamically allocated array? If so then: `int(*addition(/*...*/))[100] { return new int[100][100]; }` – truely uggly syntax, I now... An alias can help you make the definition more readable: `typedef int(Matrix)[100]; Matrix* addition(Matrix* x, Matrix* y);`

Comment: Packing the array into a struct would make the whole stuff much easier as well: `struct Matrix { int data[100][100]; };` – that would allow for extending later on, too, such as `Matrix operator+(Matrix& m1, Matrix& m2);` which then would make possible to have matrix operations such as `Matrix m3 = m1 + m2;`.

Comment: Not possible. Using vectors and/or pointers is the right way. If you're not allowed to use those, then you're not expected to (and can't) have dynamic arrays.

Comment: You can kind of have dynamic arrays (size known at runtime), if you know an upper limit. Create a large array and only use the actual size in your loop boundaries.

Comment: So, no feedback and wild guessing possible. I need more clarity and VTC

Comment: You might consider as well having a 1D array of size rows*columns and calculate the offsets manually, 2D `[x][y]` corresponds to 1D `[x * columns + y]` (which is what the compiler under the hoods calculates for the 2D variant anyway), giving you back full flexibility. Again packing that into a separate class would provide you with almost endless possibilities, including re-introducing 2D index syntax (`[][]`) with a bit of extra work...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So here is my suggested solution. This code is not using C++ containers such as `std::vector` or others. But it works dynamically, i.e. your matrices can be any size. If I read things correctly in the comments and assuming this is to do with a class, teaching C/C++, I think this is to get a deeper understanding of pointers, before making use of the convenient containers in C++. This way you get an understanding of what they do under the surface. It is not as easy as it might seem and I left some commented out code so you can see how I found a quick way of testing it without having to type in numbers every time. To understand how the code actually works read about and play with pointers! You will not learn by just copying this code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int** createMatrix(int numRows, int numColumns)
{
    int** matrix;
    matrix = new int *[numRows];

    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
        matrix[r] = new int[numColumns];

    return matrix;
}

void deleteMatrix(int **matrix)
{    
    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; r++)
       delete[] matrix[r];

    delete[] matrix;
}

void sumMatrix(int** matrixA, int** matrixB, int** const sum, int numRows, int numColumns)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] + matrixB[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix(int **matrix, int numRows, int numColumns)
{
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    
    //int numRows = 2, numColumns = 2; 
    int numRows, numColumns;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: "; 
    cin >> numRows;

    cout << "Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin >> numColumns;

    int** sohaib = createMatrix(numRows, numColumns);
    int** waleed = createMatrix(numRows, numColumns);
    int** sum = createMatrix(numRows, numColumns);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            //sohaib[i][j] = 1;
            //waleed[i][j] = 2;
            cin >> sohaib[i][j];
            cin >> waleed[i][j];
        }
    }

    sumMatrix(sohaib, waleed, sum, numRows, numColumns);

    printMatrix(sum, numRows, numColumns);

    deleteMatrix(sohaib);
    deleteMatrix(waleed);
    deleteMatrix(sum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `deleteMatrix` doesn't release the individual rows that you allocate in your `for`.  Also, did you mean to do `new int[numColumns]`?

Comment: The OP said no pointers allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm having a look at the points made right now...

Comment: Addressed issues pointed out by @StephenNewell. Many thanks for that again. In deed that was both wrong.

Comment: @Sebastian is right, it says no pointers (and now vectors, i.e. no std containers I guess). So this is also not a valid solution. But as someone else has pointed out, there is no way to work with arrays and have something dynamic. In deed the closest you can get is work with matrices that have an upper limit, as shown in another answer here.

Comment: To be fair the restrictions were only specified by the OP in the comments